# Cannot read urllib error message once it is read()

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, urllib

My problem is with error handling of the python urllib error object. I am unable to read the error message while still keeping it intact in the error object, for it to be consumed later.

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request) # request that will raise an error
response.read()
response.read() # is empty now
# Also tried seek(0), that does not work either.
```

So this how I intend to use it, but when the Exception bubbles up, the`.read()` second time is empty.

```
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    self.log.exception(err.read())
    raise err
```

I tried making a deepcopy of the err object,

```
import copy
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    err_obj_copy = copy.deepcopy(err)
    self.log.exception(
        "Method:{}\n"
        "URL:{}\n"
        "Data:{}\n"
        "Details:{}\n"
        "Headers:{}".format(method, url, data, err_obj_copy.read(), headers))
    raise err
```

but copy is unable to make a deepcopy and throws an error -
`TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'url', 'code', 'msg', 'hdrs', and 'fp'`.

How do I read the error message, while still keeping it intact in the object?

I do know how to do it using `requests`, but I am stuck with legacy code and need to make it work with `urllib`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. Worked for me.

When reading the error for the first time, save it to a variable like this: `msg = response.read().decode('utf8')`. You can then create a new `HTTPError` instance, with the message, and propagate it.

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
msg = resp.read().decode('utf8')
self.log.exception(msg)
raise HTTPError(resp.url, resp.code, resp.reason, resp.headers, io.BytesIO(bytes(msg, 'utf8')))
```

Comment: You should save the result of `resp.read()` so that you pass in the raw bytes back to `HTTPError` instead of re-encoding the text. See @jf's answer above.

Comment: Thank you @reubano. It sure is better that way. I don't understand why, at first, when I tried to pass in the raw bytes, the variable `msg` would remain as an empty `bytestring` object. I must have been doing something wrong. I think that's why I decoded the `bytestring`.

Answer (score 0):

The error object may read from the network. Network is not seekable -- you can't go back in the general case.

You could replace `err` with a new HTTPError instance that reads from a buffer (like `io.BytesIO()`) instead of the network e.g., (not tested):

```
content = err.read()
self.log.exception(content)
raise HTTPError(err.url, err.code, err.reason, err.headers, io.BytesIO(content))
```

Though I'm not sure that you should -- handle the error in a single place instead e.g., reraise a more application specific exception or leave the logging to an upstream handler.