# How to mock raise urllib errors

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, urllib, pytest-mock

After reading [this in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#number-1), I am catching the `HTTPError` and `URLError` exceptions in `get_response_from_external_api` that the `make_request_and_get_response` (via `urllib`'s `urlopen` call) can raise:

foo.main.py

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import contextlib
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

def make_request_and_get_response(q):
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(q)) as response:
        return response.read()

def get_response_from_external_api(q):
    try:
        resp = make_request_and_get_response(q)
        return resp
    except URLError as e:
        print('Got a URLError: ', e)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print('Got a HTTPError: ', e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = 'test'
    result = get_response_from_external_api(query)
    print(result)
```

While testing the `get_response_from_external_api` method, I am **trying to mock raising the `HTTPError` and `URLError` exceptions**:

foo.test_main.py

```py
from foo.main import get_response_from_external_api

import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

def test_get_response_from_external_api_with_httperror(capsys):
    with patch('foo.main.make_request_and_get_response') as mocked_method:
        with pytest.raises(HTTPError) as exc:
            mocked_method.side_effect = HTTPError()  # TypeError
            resp = get_response_from_external_api(mocked_method)

            out, err = capsys.readouterr()
            assert resp is None
            assert 'HTTPError' in out
            assert str(exc) == HTTPError

def test_get_response_from_external_api_with_urlerror(capsys):
    with patch('foo.main.make_request_and_get_response') as mocked_method:
        with pytest.raises(URLError) as exc:
            mocked_method.side_effect = URLError()  # TypeError
            resp = get_response_from_external_api(mocked_method)

            out, err = capsys.readouterr()
            assert resp is None
            assert 'URLError' in out
            assert str(exc) == URLError
```

But I get a `TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'url', 'code', 'msg', 'hdrs', and 'fp'`. I am new to python mocks syntax and looking for examples.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41922833/12367781) but I cannot see how this can be applied in my case where the return value of the `urllib.urlopen` (via `get_response_from_external_api`) is outside of the scope of the except-block. Not sure if I should instead mock the whole `urllib.urlopen.read` instead as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204230/12367781)?

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to mock parts of `urlopen` - by mocking your function to raise an exception you are ensuring that `urlopen` will not get called.

Since you are creating these exceptions to check that your error-handling code is working, they don't need to be complete - they need only contain the minimum information required to satisfy your tests.

[HTTPError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError) expects five arguments:

- a url
- an HTTP status code
- an error message
- the request headers
- a file-like object (the body of the response)

For mocking purposes these could all be `None`, but it may be helpful to construct an object that looks like a real error.  If something is going to read the "file-like object" you can pass `io.BytesIO` instance containing an example response, but this doesn't seem necessary, based on the code in the question.

```
>>> h = HTTPError('http://example.com', 500, 'Internal Error', {}, None)
>>> h
<HTTPError 500: 'Internal Error'>
```

[URLError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.URLError) expects a single argument, which can be a string or an exception instance; for mocking purposes, a string is sufficient.

```
>>> u = URLError('Unknown host')
>>> u

URLError('Unknown host')
```

Here is the code from the question, amended to take the above into account.  And there is no need to pass the mocked function to itself - just pass an arbitrary string.  I removed the `with pytest.raises` blocks because the exception is captured in your code's try/except blocks: you are testing that your code handles the exception itself, not that the exception percolates up to the test function.

```
from foo.main import get_response_from_external_api

import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

def test_get_response_from_external_api_with_httperror(capsys):
    with patch('foo.main.make_request_and_get_response') as mocked_method:
        mocked_method.side_effect = HTTPError('http://example.com', 500, 'Internal Error', {}, None)
        resp = get_response_from_external_api('any string')
        assert resp is None
        out, err = capsys.readouterr()
        assert 'HTTPError' in out


def test_get_response_from_external_api_with_urlerror(capsys):
    with patch('foo.main.make_request_and_get_response') as mocked_method:
        mocked_method.side_effect = URLError('Unknown host')
        resp = get_response_from_external_api('any string')
        assert resp is None
        out, err = capsys.readouterr()
        assert 'URLError' in out
```

Finally, you need to reverse the order of your try except blocks - `HTTPError` is a subclass of `URLError`, so you need to test for it first, otherwise it will be handled by the `except URLError` block.